# shell command inside the linux daemon

Tags: c++, c, linux, daemon

I have written the `daemon in C/C++ in linux`.
Now I want to get the out put of `ls -l` (list directory) command inside daemon and write output of command to the file.

I know how to write to the file from my daemon, but,

I don't know how to execute ls -l command and get the output in buffer.

Here is the code...

```
   /* Create a new SID for the child process */
    sid = setsid();

    if (sid < 0) {
      /* Log any failures here */

      ofs << "set sid : fail";
      ofs.close();
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        ofs << "\nchdir :" << chdir(filePath) << "\n";

    /* Change the current working directory */
    if ((chdir(filePath)) < 0) {
      /* Log any failures here */

      ofs << "chdir : fail";
      ofs.close();
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);       

        while(1){
            //here I want to execute the ls -l and get output of the command
        }
```

Comment: consider to put some code

Comment: create a pipe, fork, dup2, execve?

Comment: Daemon runs in bg. So, you can get its o/p in a file using a redirection or something.

Comment: This file can be anything, even your stdin/stdout (terminal, tty).

Comment: `cout << "\nFork failed"` there is no shift operator for character pointers or string contants in C.

Comment: use printf("\nFork failed");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) that executes a shell command and  return the output as a pipe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE* pipe = popen("ls -l", "r");
if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
```

---

You can also use [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to execute any shell command:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

To get the output of `ls -l`, forward it to a file `ls -l >> myls.log` than read that file.

```
system("ls -l >> myls.log");
```

Comment: So in order to get output every time I should redirect to the file and then read from the file only? Can't I get out put in buffer instead of writing to the file ?

Comment: You can use `popen` that returns output as a file. Answer updated

Comment: bulls eye... :)...this (popen() )is the thing I wanted....perfect link ...Thank you so much :)...I am accepting your help... :)...and up voting too..